# Как сделать локальное расширение функционала тэга <img ...>, которое бы действовало только в определённой боковой панели?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-filters

```
img {
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  filter: grayscale(1); /* Firefox 35+ */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
}

/* Disable grayscale on hover */
img:hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

Этот код использует css фильтры. При добавлении в файл style.css Wordpress'a превращает все картинки (которые описываются тэгом ) в серые, а при наведении мышки показывает цвета. Но проблема в том, что он одинаково действует на все картинки на странице. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы это действовало только в одной боковой панели (sidebar)?
Благодарю за внимание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно более точно указать ссылку к этому тэгу, например:

```
.sidebar img:hover {
}
```

Comment: Попробовал. Картинки в sidebar'e никак не впечатлились. Файл, где кодируется sidebar, называется sidebar.php, и код в нём <div id="sidebar...>...</div>

Comment: В конечном итоге помогло, спасибо!